# How should api token be passed to functions?

Tags: python

In my main function I get the API token from my environment variables. Should I use global or pass it in as an argument to all the functions that uses the api_token?

```
def main():
    api_token = os.environ.get('API_TOKEN')

def request_data():
    url = 'https://api.example.com/search'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(api_token)
    params = {}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

def update_data():
    url = 'https://api.example.com/update'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(api_token)
    data = {}
    r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Third option: Make your functions methods of a common class and make the token an object attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a class to encapsulate the requesting logic?

```
def main():
    api_token = os.environ.get('API_TOKEN')
    api = Api(api_token)
    api.request_data()

class Api(object):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def request_data(self):
        url = 'https://api.example.com/search'
        header = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(self.token)
        params = {}
        r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

    def update_data(self):
        url = 'https://api.example.com/update'
        header = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(self.token)
        data = {}
        r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Like this approach but can’t I also define the token in the __init__ method of the class instead of the main() function?

Comment: Yes. But it's generally a good idea to inject such dependencies into classes instead of the class getting the dependency itself. It makes unit testing much easier. By passing the token to `__init__` you can pass a mock token during tests very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Using `requests.Session()` is really helpful in this case:

Example without updating headers:

```
s = requests.Session()  # Start session

resp = s.get("http://httpbin.org/headers")

print(resp.json()["headers"])
```

Which outputs the default headers:

```
{'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}
```

Now if you want to add something like an `api_token` you can use `s.headers.update()`:

```
s.headers.update({"Auth": "Authkey"})

resp = s.get("http://httpbin.org/headers")

print(resp.json()["headers"])
```

New output:

```
{'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Auth': 'Authkey', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}
```

Now until you start a new session, anything you add to the headers will stick!